# jquery datatables default sort by using asSorting

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

i read already some questions/answers but i don't find the same exactly

so my question is following:

can i sort one datatable by using asSorting only (ie, not aaSorting)

here is my work on http://jsfiddle.net/dsea/SFRXL/22/ and you see, the 1srt column is 'asc' and not 'desc' like I expected

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "aoColumns": [
        { "sType" : "numeric", "asSorting" : ["desc", "asc", "desc"] },
        { "sType" : "string" },
        null
    ]
} );
} );
```

thanks a lot
dsea

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use aaSorting?
asSorting only defines the behavior for that column, not the table. It doesn't dictate how the table is sorted, because what if you defined asSorting for every column? Then what is it supposed to do?